# Render HTML or GSP as a PDF and save it on server

Tags: pdf, grails, plugins, rendering, pdf-rendering

I have an html template which I need to render as a .PDF and then save that pdf file on server. I'm using "rendering" plugin of grails. I'm able to render file as PDF but I don't understand how to save it on server location and not on user's system. Can anybody please help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pdfRenderingService provided by the plugin allows you to call render and get back an OutputStream. Using that output stream you can write that to a file on your server. The [documentation](http://gpc.github.io/grails-rendering/docs/manual/guide/3.%20Rendering.html) explains the basics of using the service.

Your code may look something like this:

```
new File("report.pdf").withOutputStream { outputStream ->
            outputStream << pdfRenderingService.render(template: '/report/report', model: [serial: 12345])
        }
```

Comment: Okk.. Well actually I'm not that good with file writing and all. How to provide a dir path to grails program where it can download and save pdf file. And this whole process would be called in a scheduler, so can we do this automatically ?

Comment: That's difficult to answer since you haven't given any examples of what you have already tried/written. Stackoverflow is used to answer specific programming questions.

Comment: Hey actually your answer gave me a hint how to do it. But I used different plugin.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Is it possible to use an html/gsp string for the template field instead of a view directory?

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually I changed my plugin. Got Wkhtmltopdf plugin of grails more helpful. you can find it here --
 https://github.com/quorak/grails-wkhtmltopdf

Also instructions regarding using this plugin you can find on the same link or here --

[https://github.com/quorak/grails-wkhtmltopdf]

Using this you can get "bytes" which you can write to file system.